# Jenkins Build cannot find node [X] in package [Y]. Failed roslaunch check

Tags: jenkins, ros

I have added a python script in one of the ros packages it's working fine on my local system but failing roslaunch check on Jenkins.

[/home/jenkinsbuild/jenkins/ws/autobiom_robo/label/ROS_MELODIC/src/git_autobiom_robo/launch/autobiom.launch]:    cannot find node[rawdatadump] in package [data_dump]

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, I have not set the executable bit.

```
chmod +X filename
```